# Composer, Participants and User-Management

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When triggering a transaction with the "composer-cli" one has to specify the "enrollId" and the "secret" to be able to send the request. So transaction is fired in the context of a given fabric-user.

I was asking myself if there is a way to map the identity of the fabric-user firing the transaction to a given "participant" from the Participant Registry (in the composer JS code, which implements business logic)?

Are these two layers of authentication completely separated? If yes, then how is one supposed to identify in the JS code that a given participant (in composer terminology) is firing the transaction? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the docs here:
https://fabric-composer.github.io/managing/identity-issue.html

The issue identity / revoke identity CLI commands are used to map a Fabric user to a Composer participant.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically specify user/secret when invoking a transaction via REST API so that it gets executed in a context of a given participant? Its just if we start the REST API server using "admin" identity, all subsequent invocations of API methods would be run in the "admin" context, right? Is there a more flexible way of setting the identity when invoking REST?